# How to pass DISPLAY information in lua language?

Tags: lua, archlinux, awesome-wm

I am running Arch linux and trying to configure awesome WM for two graphics cards with two Screens. So, I am running awesome twice, each one on different display. So, in

```
.xprofile
```

> DISPLAY=:0.1 awesome &

while awesome running in DISPLAY=:0.0 too. Although, those two awesome instances running with one configuration file, written in lua language.

So, I want to write an If statement in this lua language configuration file, which checks if DISPLAY= first or second screen to assign different tags in each screen. Is this possible? I have minimal knowledge of lua language and i am willing to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about awesome, but in stock Lua you can use `os.getenv("DISPLAY")` to get the value of the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

So you do something like this:

```
if os.getenv("DISPLAY")==":0.0" then
  -- do something
else
  -- do something else
end
```